# Servo/audio synchronization in animatronics on RPi. Considering FFT solution

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, fft

I've been working on an animatronic shooting gallery using a Raspberry Pi B+ and an Arduino Mega. Overall, things are going well except for one detail. I'm having trouble keeping the motor movements in sync with sound.

For example, say I got this talking pig. You hit the target and the pig says "Hey, Kid! Watch were you're pointing that thing! You'll put your eye out!" or something like that. Problem is, the motors making the pig move can't keep up with the audio. They lag behind, getting out of sync with the audio. The longer the routine, the further they fall behind. What's more, it doesn't lag behind at a consistent rate. It seems to depend on what else the computer is doing at the time. For example, I had Audacity running at the same time as my program was running, and there was noticeably more lag then when my program was the only program running. I also notice a slight difference in lag between running my program in IDLE vs running from terminal.

Some of my targets are more sensitive to synchronization than others, for example, if I had a rocket that went up to a whooshing sound, it's not really an issue if the motor moves a little faster or slower, but mouth movements look terrible if they're off by more than maybe a tenth of a second.

To control my motors, I use a pickled list of tuples each containing 0: time in ms after beginning of routine for the position signal to be sent, 1: the number of the motor for the signal to be sent to, and 2: the position of the motor. The main program loops through all the targets and gives each a chance to see if it is time for it to send the next motor position command.

Here is my current code:

```
import time
import pygame.mixer
import os
import cPickle as pickle
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from Adafruit_PWM_Servo_Driver import PWM

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
chan_list = [17,18]
GPIO.setup(chan_list, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.FALLING)
GPIO.add_event_detect(18, GPIO.FALLING)


pygame.mixer.init(channels=1, frequency=22050)
pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(10)
pwm = PWM(0x40)
pwm.setPWMFreq(60)

game_on = 1

class Bot:
    def __init__(self, folder, servopins):

        self.startExecute = 0
        self.finishExecute = 0

        self.folder = folder # name of folder containing routine sound and motor position data
        self.servoPins = servopins #list of servo motor pins for this bot
##        self.IRpin = IRpin
        self.startTime = 0 # start time of curent routine in ms. begins at 0ms
        self.counter = 0 #next frame of routine to be executed
        self.isRunning = 0 #1 if bot is running a a routine 0 if not target inactive if 1
        self.routine = 0 # position of current routine in self.routines
##        self.numRoutines = 0 
        self.sounds = [] #list containing sound objects for routines. One per routine
        self.routines = [] #list of lists of tuples containing time, motor number, and motor position. One per routine
        self.list_dir = os.listdir(self.folder) # creates a list containing the names of all routine sound and motor position data files
        self.list_dir.sort()
        self.currentFrame = () # tuple containing current routine frame containing execution time, motor number and motor position waiting to be executed

        # appends all routine sound files into a list
        for filo in self.list_dir:
            if filo.endswith('.wav'):
                self.sounds.append(pygame.mixer.Sound(self.folder + filo))
                print filo
        #appends all routine motor position files into a list
        for filo in self.list_dir:
            if filo.endswith('.pkl'):
                self.incoming = open(self.folder + filo)
                self.pklroutine = pickle.load(self.incoming)
                self.routines.append(self.pklroutine)
                self.incoming.close()
                print filo
#        self.sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(str(self.routine) + '.wav')
#        self.motorfile = open(str(self.routine) + '.pkl')

    # starts a routine running. resets counter to first frame of routine.
    #Starts routine timer. Starts routine sound object playing. Loads first frame of routine
    def run(self):
        self.isRunning = 1
        self.startTime = round(time.clock() * 1000)
        self.sounds[self.routine].play()
        self.currentFrame = self.routines[self.routine][self.counter]


    def execute(self):

        if self.counter == 0:

            self.startExecute = round(time.clock() * 1000)

        if self.currentFrame[0] <= (round(time.clock() * 1000) - self.startTime):
            pwm.setPWM(self.servoPins[self.currentFrame[1]-1], 0, int(round(150 + ((self.currentFrame[2] * 2.6)))))
            if self.counter < (len(self.routines[self.routine]) -2):
                self.counter = self.counter + 1
                self.currentFrame = self.routines[self.routine][self.counter]
            else:
                print (round(time.clock() * 1000) - self.startTime)

                self.finishExecute = round(time.clock() * 1000)
                self.counter = 0
                self.isRunning = 0
                if self.routine < (len(self.routines) - 1):
                    self.routine = self.routine + 1
                else:
                    self.routine = 0



bot1 = Bot('Pig/', [0,1])
bot2 = Bot('Goat/', [2,3])

while 1:

    if game_on:
        if GPIO.event_detected(17):
            bot1.run()
        if GPIO.event_detected(18):
            bot2.run()



    if bot1.isRunning:
        bot1.execute()
    if bot2.isRunning == 1:
        bot2.execute()
```

The list of tuples is created using two other programs, one on the Arduino Mega, and another on my PC using Python. The arduino is connected to a couple of potentiometers connected to +5V and ground, with the signal voltage coming from the middle terminal into an analog input. The arduino converts this analog value to a motor position in degrees, and sends that over the serial port to the PC that saves it in a tuple along with the motor number, and time that the byte was received, appends the tuple to a list, then at the end of the program, saves it in a pkl file. I will provide that code if somebody really wants to see it, but I don't believe the problem lies within the data produced by this process.

If you have any suggestions about how I could fix this code to make it work, that would be the preferable solution, because the solution I'm contemplating now seems like it might just be one massive PITA.

I'm thinking that I could use one audio channel (say, the left channel) for my audio, then in the other channel, I could have sine waves of different frequencies and amplitudes with each frequency being assigned to a specific motor. Say for example I have this one motor that moves a mouth. This motor will have an assigned frequency of 1000 Hz. Whenever the mouth needs to be open, there will be a 1000 Hz sine wave in the motor control channel. I would use an Arduino Mega to detect that sine wave, and send the PWM signal to the motor to move to a certain position. The position *may* even be determined by the amplitude of the sine wave. To make things a little simpler, I could just have 3 positions for the mouth, closed (no signal), open a little (small amplitude signal), and open a little more (larger amplitude signal).

All of this would be done using this FFT library: http://wiki.openmusiclabs.com/wiki/ArduinoFFT

I would need to build a circuit to convert the AC signal from the RPi to a 0-5V signal. I have found this circuit [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ68q.png) that looks like it plausibly might work, assuming I can find a way to cleanly amplify the signal from the RPi to +/- 2.5V. [Source](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/148085/fft-beat-detection-circuit)

Other than that, I don't know how difficult or effective it would be to implement this solution. For one, I'm not sure if I can send PWM signals to the motors and run the FFT library at the same time, and I've never worked with this library, or had any experience with FFT at all.

My fallback solution is to design the shooting gallery so that it is less dependent on synchronization. This would involve such compromises such as just making the mouth open and close at a steady rate rather than trying to make it move in sync with audio, and keeping triggered routines short (<= 5 seconds)

Okay, problem defined, now on to specific questions:

What can I do to make the current version of the program work without having to resort to analyzing a bunch of sine waves using FFT?

Failing that, any suggestions on the input circuit? What could I use to cleanly amplify the RPi signal to +/- 2.5V, and will the circuit I linked to actually work to convert that signal to a 0V-5V signal readable by an Arduino analog input?

Will using the FFT library interfere with sending the PWM signals to the motors?

How much of a PITA will it be to extract usable data from a bunch of sine waves using FFT?

The documentation for the FFT library is a little lacking, How do I set the range of frequencies to analyze? I see that it starts at 0 Hz(DC), but what's the high end? Can I set that? I only need maybe 30 usable bins. What frequencies should I use to get the clearest signals? I'm guessing I don't want to use the highest and lowest, because the lowest would take longer to detect, and the highest will be more distorted due to the poor quality of the audio coming out of the RPi. Should I set it to 64 bins and use the middle 30? And again, how do I determine the center frequency of each bin?

Answer (score 0):

Gosh, who will answer to all these Qs.
1. Your program is doing OK, Raspi is responsible for your trouble.
OS has its timer which interrupts every process, usually 100 times per second. Then OS does what it needs to do and chooses another process to be active. Then after X MS or US, according to OSes preference, that process is interrupted, and so on. This causes your program to pause at least 0.01 sec (best case). I don't know for Raspi B+, but on B kernel interrupts were interfering with software PWM as well, because, as far as I remember, Raspi B has only one hardware PWM pin. You have more than one servo, which have to be updated every 20 MS with correct duty cycle to keep the wanted position. Your idea to use audio output to control servoes is really not so bad.
For that, you do not need FFT, you just generate the sine wave according to formula (use numpy):
    sine = A*np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(how_long)*freq/fs)
Where A is amplitude, freq is desired frequency of sine, and fs is the sample rate of audio output. how_long is number of samples you want to generate. Anyway, PWM is not a sine, it is a square signal. So you would not even need that. Just N samples of zeros and N samples of 1.
I can recommend implementing a signal check from Arduino. You tell a motor, start to move, when it does, play the sound. Slow down motors to be able to catch up with sound.
The best way of doing this would be to make your motor controler out of some MCU, and not use Raspi GPIO for that. Then talk to MCU using I2C or RS232. This works very well.
If you have multiple motors, take care that chosen MCU has enough hardware PWM pins, or choose one with high oscilator frequency and add demultiplexor to it.
Yes, if you use FFT, or start another program, or something, PWM will suffer badly.
I think numpy is included in Raspbian and FFT works very well on it, but you would not need it anyway. May be, but just may be, try pyaudio or alsaaudio instead of pygame to see who is faster in responding. On PyPI you have one nice module SWMixer, that turns pyaudio into pygame.mixer(), so you would not need to do anything extra. Although, I think, this will be very slow because of manual mixing. But pyaudio can open multiple streams on which you can write parallely. Also, it would be great, for this purpose to have a real time OS.
There are some prepared images for Raspi. I found, few years back, an image from Machinoid, precompiled Xenomai with Debian. The trouble was that audio driver did not work. It is possible that somebody fixed that. On RTOS, you can specify time in which some action should be performed, thus making it atomic. I.e. OS will do all to perform it in specified time. In that manner OSes interrupts and switching to other processes are governed by timeout of required action.
You choose the easiest solution for you. I would firstly see what can I do with the feedback connection, if it does not work, I would try with audio, and if this does not work, I would use external IC for PWM.
Audio approach has a limit. You cannot make two pigs talk at the same time. :D
Enjoy yourself. I would! :D

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified that I am using an Adafruit Servo/PWM Hat.

Comment: The Idea with FFT is to have several Sine waves going into the Arduino, which the arduino then reads as motor positions for several (up to 30) motors. each frequency controls a different motor.

Comment: I am using pygame.mixer because I can play a large number of audio channels. If I can get PyAudio to do the same, I may be able to use stream.get_time() to tie the motor movements to specific points in the audio stream.

It's fine if either, or both the audio stream, and motor position data stream speed up and/or slow down, I only deed for them to stay in sync.

If I could get PyAudio to play multiple independant streams simultaneously, and asynchronously, and stream.get_time() gives me the exact point in the audio stream so that I can tie it into the motor data stream, that should work.

Comment: The problem with Pygame.mixer is that there is no way to get it to tell me the playback time. At one point, I was using TKsnack, which does have a way to get current playback time, and it worked beautifully, but I couldn't get it to play multiple asychronous streams.

Comment: PyAudio can open multiple streams on all my machines, but I didn't tried it on Raspi.

Comment: Oh, no, Mozilla did it again. Posted a comment before I finished it. Sorry.

Comment: PyAudio can open multiple streams and playback written data at the same time. It works on all my machines, but I didn't try it on Raspi. I do not know whether this is OS or hardware enabled. (for PortAudio).
And what is the limit of streams. You can mix your sounds manually. There would be some speed loss because of that, but not much.

Comment: I'm experimenting with swmixer right now, with positive results so far. It supposedly adds some value to PyAudio, I thought by adding "mixer" functionality. If PyAudio already supports that, then I'm not sure what value PyAudio adds other than maybe making mixing easier. I couldn't understand how to use PyAudio, But I'm not having too much trouble with swmixer.

What kind of VooDoo do you use to mix multiple streams in PyAudio? Something involving NumPy, maybe?

Comment: To generate more than one sine wave i.e. 2 sines with different freqs, you just add them.
(0.5*sine1)+(0.5*sine2).Their lenghts must match. Do not complicate your life with FFT, because IFFT is much slower than FFT. And not to mention how much slower than adding and deviding. But you will then have to use correlation or FFT on arduino to analyze the input, which will slow you down again. You should do something else for that communication. It is possible, and it is used with mobile phones, to simulate RS232 using audio output. It should not be hard, perhaps there is library somewhere already.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pay much attention to imports. If I did, I wouldn't suggest you switching to external servo controler. :D

Comment: The magic is just transforming audio data into numpy array (you can do that at load time) then adding them together, like I shown you with sines, then transforming array back to binary stream. I suggested swMixer because it does just that for you, using numpy. What loose of speed do you have by using this? Is pygame faster?

Comment: swMixer uses one pyaudio stream, which you can access by hacking into swMixer, to get gettime() you need, but you wouldn't know which audio exactly was sent out. You can keep timestamps yourself, use PyAudio stream get_write_latency() or whatever its called, and some more magical numbers to add and subtract, and see when is your concreete sound at the output.

Comment: I forgot to add. Multiple streams as such, without mixing, you just open more than one at once, and write to first free one from a thread.

Comment: I mean, if you want to do it without either manual mixing or swMixer.

Comment: The problem with the RS232 solution, is that there would be overlap of multiple signals from each of the audio streams. I would need some signal that I could separate somehow. I've been playing around with get_position() on swmixer. I think it will do what I need it to do. It won't give me ms accuracy. It seems to increment by some multiple of chunksize, which may represent anywhere from 9 to 30 ms, but always stays within a tight enough time window of the position of audio playback that I should be able to make do.

Comment: I can't tell any difference in the speed of swmixer vs pygame,mixer. The problem with pygame.mixer was that I had no process by which to determine the current position of audio playback to sync the motors to.

Comment: I hope that swMixer will be enough then. Please, let me know, your project is very interesting.

Comment: But why on earth RS232 would not do?
You push more commands into same package. For instance, when one pig is talking, only motor 1 gets commands, but when two pigs are talking at the same time you say move motor 1 and 2.
At baudrates of 9600 or 15200 the reception of packages is practically instantaneous. I did this with robot arm with 6 joints. All can move at the same time, although they receive commands serially.

Comment: If you do it using 1 audio channel as RS232 TX, You just send a packet of cleverly constructed commands at the beggining of your sound.
I doubt you have any sound that is shorter than a RS232 packet with few series of commands even if for 20 motors.
When you are not sending any data (commands), just send "\0" to have constant stream on both channels.
With some work, it should be OK. But I hope swMixer solves the problem.

Comment: I just re-read the SWMixer code. get_position() gives you a multiple of chunksize because audio is written in chunks to the output.
This is the least possible frame unit you can get.
When you say stop() or pause(), last chunk will be played in its entirety.
Nathan Whitehead didn't use stream.stop_stream() to force pyaudio to cut off where it is.
If you define too big chunk, it becomes ridiculous. You say stop() and playback continues one second or more on, and then stops.

Comment: To increase "resolution" of get_position() try resizing a chunk.
Use swmixer.set_chunksize(). I successfully used chunks of 256 samples on Raspi without problems. Any less will introduce stuttering. Maybe this is too low for SWMixer because of software mixing, wouldn't know. But 512 should work.

Comment: I haven't tried installing PyAudio on my RPi B+, yet, but from what I've seen on Google, people are having a lot of trouble with it. I'm still considering other options. If I sent a 30 Hz square wave from the arduino, to one of the pins on the RPi, could I be certain that it would catch every one of them using event_detected() ? (or at least 99.9% of them, I could live with a 0.1% slip) and can I count on the RPi to play back the sounds at a consistent rate every time?

Comment: I'm not clear on how embedding RS232 data into my audio is going to solve my time problem. Seems like I need to either tie my motor positions into playback position, or let the arduino handle time. Seems like if I were going to use serial, I would just do it the regular way using serial over USB.

Comment: You can count, certainly, but it also depends for how long will you be emitting 30 Hz, First and last events might slip. Middle will be mostly OK.

Comment: I installed PyAudio on Raspbian on my Raspi B. Worked like a charm. But, people don't realise that GUI, XFCE at least, reserves audiocard for itself, often using PulseAudio server. You have to force restart alsa before you use portaudio, or any alsa depended software. If you won't use GUI at all, you are safe.

Comment: Packing RS232 in audio stream which runs paralelly with audio would enable you sending commands at right time when sound is played. Using USB2Serial will again require manual sync, and you will again have a loss of speed from every side, because OS will double its interrupts to write to serial. Anyway Raspberry has its own RS232 pin, you just have to remove terminal from it. And see about voltages.

Comment: Aha, yeah, you have PyAudio on apt-get repo, but you probably now that already. :D

Comment: And, thinking of other options, when Raspbian had a problem with BCM chip going to sleep suddenly and emitting a stupid click, I thought it was PyAudio's fault and implemented my player using aplay as connection to the card. I just piped to it, and it played it all dutifully.